# How to make windows 8.1 first boot priorty in gnu grub menu

Tags: grub2

I have dual boot of windows 8.1 and ubuntu 12.04.

The problem is every time I turn on my netbook  ubuntu will be the priority in the gnu grub menu.

If I don't select windows it will automatically boot into ubuntu...
How do I make windows first boot priority before ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

In file /etc/default/grub you have a line:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

which you can change to indicate the windows selection, but every time a new kernel gets added, that number would change.
  A more permanent method is to rename the file /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober to 06_os-prober
(or the custom file if you put your windows boot paragraph into one of those).  The files are run in order, so that should always put Windows first.

Comment: That means after i change the file the windows will be the priority?...thanks for the info

Comment: Yes, it will put Windows first in the list, and that is the default position.